# Bringing low voltage cable through exterior wall

Tags: exterior, low-voltage, coaxial-cable

I've got a 1 1/4" rough diameter hole through exterior wall that I am bringing a Starlink low voltage cable through. The exterior wall will have snow up against it at times and even up to and over the hole. I am trying to decide

1. the most weatherproof way to bring this cable through (the end of the cable is about 1.125" and cannot be taken apart) that is also
2. least obtrusive. The exterior single gang box is pretty large and hefty.

Are there 1.5" grommets available that are trust worthy to seal and bring the cable through? Or should I bring a piece of pipe through the hole and thread it to the back of the box and seal the pipe?

Then what about bringing the cable up through the bottom of the box? Use a cable gland? Lots of questions here.

[image: exterior wall]

Comment: As long as you don't need to change it often, you can seal it either with expanding foam (spray it into the hole after you run *and test* the cables) or duct seal putty.

Comment: Make an answer out of that, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact. It'll get my vote.

Comment: Whatever method you decide to use, don't forget to include a drip loop if the cable is entering the house from above.

Comment: search `cable grommet fits starlink`  if you're existing hole is not oversized, then don't even use the box.  and a litle silicone.   you can find plenty of pics online.

Answer (score 1):

Get a piece of closed-cell type foam rubber sheet, maybe 3/16"-1/4" thick.  Cut it to fit the box, cut a hole in the middle, insert between box and wall.